# `String#sub` method returning incorrect value on the first execution

Tags: ruby

I am trying to make a UUID into a properly conformed UUID by inserting a hyphen within each section of the substring.

```
test = "CB13DBB20A9945CC86F11914C979C761"
#The first one will return '----' so essentially the $1 to $5 are returned as emptys
test.sub(/(\h{8})(\h{4})(\h{4})(\h{4})(\h{12})/, "#{$1}-#{$2}-#{$3}-#{$4}-#{$5}")
#Returns the ideal result of CB13DBB2-0A99-45CC-86F1-1914C979C761
test.sub(/(\h{8})(\h{4})(\h{4})(\h{4})(\h{12})/, "#{$1}-#{$2}-#{$3}-#{$4}-#{$5}")
```

As you can see, the first run of the function does not work, but the second does. Any ideas would be great. As additional information,

```
test.match(/(\h{8})(\h{4})(\h{4})(\h{4})(\h{12})/){|m| "#{$1}-#{$2}-#{$3}-#{$4}-#{$5}"}
```

will work on the first time instead. Single quotes and double quotes do not affect anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference the pattern matches like this.

```
test.sub(/(\h{8})(\h{4})(\h{4})(\h{4})(\h{12})/, '\1-\2-\3-\4-\5')
```

The reason you are seeing this behaviour is explained in the Ruby Docs:

> If replacement is a String it will be substituted for the matched text. **It may contain back-references to the pattern’s capture groups of the form \d, where d is a group number**, or \k, where n is a group name. If it is a double-quoted string, both back-references must be preceded by an additional backslash. **However, within replacement the special match variables, such as &$, will not refer to the current match**.

Comment: Why `gsub` instead of `sub` here?

Comment: Yes, `sub` would be better as it only applies once.

Answer (score 4):

While this can be accomplished using regex, I'd go with substrings:

```
require 'pp'

uuid = 'CB13DBB20A9945CC86F11914C979C761'
pp [uuid[0, 8], uuid[8, 4], uuid[12, 4], uuid[16, 4], uuid[20, 12]]
# => ["CB13DBB2", "0A99", "45CC", "86F1", "1914C979C761"]

puts [
  uuid[0, 8], uuid[8, 4], uuid[12, 4], uuid[16, 4], uuid[20, 12]
].join('-')
# => CB13DBB2-0A99-45CC-86F1-1914C979C761
```

Because the use of offsets and lengths can be a bit of a chore when writing that code, here's an alternate using `unpack` with only the lengths:

```
lengths = [8, 4, 4, 4, 12]
uuid.unpack(lengths.map{ |l| "a#{ l }" }.join).join('-')
# => "CB13DBB2-0A99-45CC-86F1-1914C979C761"
```

Comment: Where do you see the benefits of not using the regex here? Performance?

Comment: Maintainability. Regex are very powerful but usually take more time to put together because they are harder to understand, and can go very badly astray in wonderful ways. I have seen more badly written and misused regex than any other sort of data manipulation, and have had to spend more time fixing them in my job, along with more time explaining why they were wrong -- it's always something subtle the developer didn't understand and spread through everything they wrote.

Comment: "With great power comes great responsibility" :)

Comment: Yes, along with the need to understand the tool. I find that people who first see a regex think everything from that point is a problem needing to be solved with regex, which is very mistaken. From that point they run around hitting everything with their regular-expression hammer. There should be a bunch of tools in a developer's toolbox, not one.

Answer (score 1):

In your example $1...$5 are replaced in the string **before** the substitution.

If you want to have them evaluated during the substitution, use the block form instead:

```
test.sub(/(\h{8})(\h{4})(\h{4})(\h{4})(\h{12})/) { "#{$1}-#{$2}-#{$3}-#{$4}-#{$5}" }
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, Ruby has SecureRandom to provide uuid's

```
require 'securerandom'
p SecureRandom.uuid #"dd1f58f8-8c42-47e0-9c08-a8d5c191c9c3"
```

Slicing the string in pieces is easily done with `String#unpack`

```
test = "CB13DBB20A9945CC86F11914C979C761"
p test.unpack("A8A4A4A4A8").join('-') #"CB13DBB2-0A99-45CC-86F1-1914C979"
```